# SQL 2005 Pivot Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to get a grip on the pivot query syntax.

I have about 20 fields worth of aggregate data all associated with 1 field, which is the category for those 20 fields (by fields I mean columns).

It looks like this

```
Category1        column1    column2    column3
Category2        column1    column2    column3
```

and so on...

What I am trying to do is pivot those results to come out like this

```
Category1    Category2    Category3

column1      column1      column1
column2      column2      column2
column3      column3      column3
```

My query looks like this

```
SELECT TOP(3) category FROM 
( 
    SELECT category FROM table 
)p 
PIVOT 
( 
    AVG(column1) as column1, AVG(column2) as column2, AVG(column3) as column3) 
    FOR category IN category 
) AS pvt;
```

I am running SQL Server 2005. Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: PIVOT or is this a transpose?

Comment: I dont know i guess. :-) Ive never done a transpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you really want [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141723(SQL.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a matrix in SSRS because I could never figure out the syntax of the PIVOT query.